# Pass generic type does not not exist on type 'T'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics

I create function what get 2 array one of them is array of order, when you have to sort your array by some order. But I get error for method 'includes'. Actually params item will be a string

```
export function getSortedArrayByOrder<T, K>(arr: T[], order: K[]): T[] {
  function getIndex(item: T): number {
    const index = order.findIndex((orderItem) => item.includes(orderItem));

    return index === -1 ? arr.length : index;
  }

  return [...arr].sort(
    (productItemA, productItemB) =>
      getIndex(productItemA) - getIndex(productItemB),
  );
}
```

Comment: In your code item which is of type `T` might not necessary be an array. For instance it could be `string` or `number`. The `includes` method exists on arrays.

Comment: Like pointed out you need to narrow your types -> `getSortedArrayByOrder<T extends string, K extends string>`